# How to select td by id

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

I am trying to run the following code but it doesn't seem to select the td by id correctly:

```
var table = $('<table/>').attr('cellspacing', '2px');
for (var r = 0; r < length; r++) {
    var trow = $("<tr/>");
    for (var c = 0; c < length; c++) {
        var cellText = $('<div/>').html(texts[r][c]).text();
        $("<td/>").addClass("cell").attr('id', 'td' + r + c).text(cellText).appendTo(trow);
    }
    trow.appendTo(table);
}
$('body').append(table);
alert($("#td00").text());
```

The alert in the end come out empty, although the texts array contains data. What is the correct way to select the td / extract the text? I need it because I wan't to add rowspan of 2 to some of the td's but can't seem to select them properly.

Comment: for (var c = 0; c < length; c++) {, what `length` ? Post full code please

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f93Z9/). Please check what's different in your code from this example.

Comment: [Your code seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/52VGz/), depending on how you determine `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.check that texts[r][c] is having the data and length is define before going to use
2. If you run the below code then it will work  
var length = 2;
        var table = $('<table/>').attr('cellspacing', '2px');
        for (var r = 0; r < length; r++) {
            var trow = $("<tr/>");
            for (var c = 0; c < length; c++) {
                var cellText = $('<div/>').html("asd").text();
                $("<td/>").addClass("cell").attr('id', 'td' + r + c).text(cellText).appendTo(trow);
            }
            trow.appendTo(table);
        }
        $('body').append(table);
        alert($("#td00").text());
        });
```

Comment: Well, the array and length were both initialized, but I tried to pull out the data before the table was inserted to the body. Changed it here so it will be easier to test. Ho stupid me..